# jQuery remove specific text in each list item

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of links to certain pages:

```html
<ul class="title-list">
  <li><a class="title "href="#">Title A Same</a></li>
  <li><a class="title "href="#">Title B Same</a></li>
  <li><a class="title "href="#">Title C Same</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to go through the list and remove 'Title' and 'Same' from each.
I am unsure if I need to use a `filter()` or `contains()` something else.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it

```js
  $(".title").each(function() {
    var x = $(this).text();
    x = x.replace('Same','');
    x = x.replace('Title','');
    $(this).text(x);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="title-list">
  <li><a class="title " href="#">Title A Same</a></li>
  <li><a class="title " href="#">Title B Same</a></li>
  <li><a class="title " href="#">Title C Same</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, went with this one - quick and easy. +1

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `html` and a function to slice all the strings.  If you wish you can assign the lengths to a variable to efficiency reasons.

```js
$(".title").html(function () {
  return $(this).html().slice("Title".length, -"same".length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="title-list">
 <li><a class="title "href="#">Title A Same</a></li>
 <li><a class="title "href="#">Title B Same</a></li>
 <li><a class="title "href="#">Title C Same</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.title-list li').each(function(li) {
  li.innerText = li.innerText.replace('Title', '').replace('Same', '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your text is fixed ,I thought you had got `length` instead of `replace`.

**html**

```
<ul class="title-list">
  <li><a class="title " href="#">Title A Same</a></li>
  <li><a class="title " href="#">Title B Same</a></li>
  <li><a class="title " href="#">Title C Same</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".title").each(function() {
   let str = $(this).text().split(" ");
   $(this).text(str[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remove with the jquery replace method.

```js
// It is possible to remove with the jquery replace method.

$(".title-list li a").each( function(){

  var a = $(this).text();
  
  var b = a.replace("Title", "");
  var c = b.replace("Same", "");
  
  $(this).text(c);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="title-list">
 <li><a class="title "href="#">Title A Same</a></li>
 <li><a class="title "href="#">Title B Same</a></li>
 <li><a class="title "href="#">Title C Same</a></li>
</ul>
```